# How to install Magento 2.4.5-p1 in docker?

Tags: docker, magento2.4.5

We have Run Below Command for install magento in docker.

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markshust/docker-magento/master/lib/onelinesetup | bash -s -- magento.test 2.4.5-p1
```

But given error.
Error Screenshot :-[image]

Comment: Please check below link..
https://medium.com/@steve_64977/how-to-setup-magento-2-4-5-on-your-local-machine-in-no-time-dd9bc24b8630

Answer (score 1):

Not directly an answer to this problem, but I would recommend you to use Warden (https://docs.warden.dev), which let you run Magento 2 in docker easily. It has all required magento services, like Elastic Search, Redis and Varnish already included.

Comment: Thank you Henry